# Unity2d animation don’t loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the player does the animation for the first time only, But I want it to loop...
I don’t know what is the problem so anyone can help!?[The animation loop problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tilSl.png)

Comment: if you select the animation clip, there is a "Loop Time" checkbox in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the animation in the project window click on it and in the inspector we can tick the Loop time. This is how normally we do it for playing idle animation which will be loop animation mostly. If you want play animation according to different logic we can do it using code.